# Saving JQuery Sortable (new order) to ASP.Net MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui-sortable

I've implemented JQuery sortable, and it works fine. The problem is I can't pass the list in its new order to a controller so i can save it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#sortable").sortable({ axis: "y" });  
    });  

    $(function() {  
        $("#submit-list").button();  

        $("#submit-list").click(function() {  
            debugger;  
            $.ajax({  
                url: '/Admin/SortedLists/',  
                data: { items: $("#sortable").sortable('toArray') },  
                type: 'post',  
                traditional: true  
            });  
        });  

    });  
</script>    

<h2>Edit Roles</h2>  

<div>  
    <ul id="sortable">  
        <% foreach (var item in Model.Roles) { %>                  
            <li>                  
                <%=Html.AttributeEncode(item.Name)%>                              
            </li>                                                                               
        <% } %>             
    </ul>  

    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit-list"/>  
</div>
```

and my controller:

```
[HttpPost]  
    public EmptyResult SortedLists(List<string> items)  
    {  
        return new EmptyResult();  
    }
```

List items comes back with the corrent number of elements - except each item are empty strings.

If the original list looks like this

1. 1 - Car
2. 2 - Boat
3. 3 - Motorcycle
4. 4 - Plane

And the user drags and resorts to be

1. 4 - Plane
2. 1 - Car
3. 3 - Motorcycle
4. 2 - Boat

How can i pass that new order? I suppose id pass the whole thing on submit, delete the entire list and resubmit this whole list

unless theres a better way? Taking advantage of Linq (using Linq to SQL) where i can insert the new order on everychange and do a submit changes?

Answer (score 9):

All I had to do was fill in the id field for each list item, [`toArray`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) method returned the list fine after that

```
<ul id="sortable">  
    <% foreach (var item in Model.Roles) { %>                  
        <li id="<%=Html.AttributeEncode(item.Name)%>"><%=Html.AttributeEncode(item.Name)%></li>                                                                                    
    <% } %>             
</ul>
```

Comment: One thing I thought about, though not sure if it's valid or not, is what if your id's conflict with something else on the page? For example, I'm using multiple lists, where each parent of the list has a numerical id, and each item has a numerical id, and the ranges of parent and child id's overlap. So doing this, can break the rule of each element having a unique id. So instead I prepend something to the id, e.g. "parent" + id, and "child" + id

Answer (score 0):

In tables you can create hidden inputs, this can help you to post  values to your Controller, than  you can easy save it ;)

It should be like this:

```
<form method="post" action="~/NameController/yourAction">
   <ul id="sortable1">

    <li><input type="hidden" id="id" name="Id"/></li>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="UserId" name="UserId"/></li>
    <li><input type="hidden" id="TeamId" name="TeamId"/></li>

 </ul>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Hope it helps;)