# ASP.Net MVC view updates

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and would like a little high level guidance.

I have the following classes, a Document which has a list of questions. Question has an order property to arrange the order of the questions for each document.

```
public class Question
{
     public int QuestionId {get; set;}
     public string Text {get; set;}
     public int Order {get; set;}
}

public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId {get; set;}
    public string DocumentName {get; set;}
    public List<Question> Questions {get; set;}
}
```

I want to show a document with its list of questions and allow the user to click a control next to the question which moves it up or down in the list.

What components should I use to update the Order property and reflect it on screen as the changes are made? I'm guessing I don't need to post until the user has made all the changes but what's the best way to update the view immediately?

Comment: have you looked at jQueryUI, and particularly the draggable() method? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Comment: What would update the Order property? jQuery? Can you give me a snippet of code that updates the property?

Comment: when you are ready to `POST`, you just call the `.serialise()` method of the `sortable` element, this will give you a `JSON` structure of the new order of the elements, all ready to send using `jQuery.ajax()`. You should be able to find a number of examples by just googling "jQuery mvc sortable ajax" - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311938/saving-jquery-sortable-new-order-to-asp-net-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript and/or jQuery will work for you. The model binder will return the objects with their updated values when you post.